# "cut the clouds off"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I sat farther along the bar and got my glass of beer and said: "You sure cut the clouds off them, buddy. I will say that for you."
>   "We just opened up," the kid said. "We got to build up trade. Been in before, haven't you, mister?"

This is from a first part of "Red Wind" by Raymond Chandler.

What exactly is the meaning of the expression "cut the clouds off" in this sentence?

Comment: The *clouds* refers to the suds on the top of the beer. Here, the bartender fills the glass closer to the brim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a compliment to the bar for its policy to serve full glasses and not hoodwinking the customers by shortchanging. you can read when you open this link.

poetry.rapgenius.com/2952067